# Is there a nice way to share a CCTextureAtlas among multiple CCTMXTiledMaps?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Good day, I'm new to cocos2d, objective-c and stack overflow.

I would like to know if it's possible to share a texture atlas instance among multiple tiled maps. I'm working on a map system, which is supposed to be able to use a really, really huge map but since it needs to run on an iPhone, I have to slice that map into many small ones to be able to cull them so I have multiple CCTMXTiledMaps in my scene which get constantly allocated and deallocated.
This works fine but on every allocation of a tiled map there is a CCTextureAtlas generated which freezes the app during the loading time and uses up a lot of memory even if the tile graphics are everywhere the same.

I looked around but all tutorials just cover the case with only one tiled map. I also tried some awful hacking, but that just caused crashes. I think, I have to setup a tiled map instance manually (not with the loadFromFile function) so I have more control of the initialization but I have no clue of what I have to consider during that.

Comment: Tip: With a non-stop block of text like this many will just skip it. Better give it some structure to make reading easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you have loaded the textures before, the tilemaps shouldn't freeze the game significantly.

Comment: I derived a class from CCTMXTiledMap and CCTMXLayer to replace the loading of a CCTexture2D with a reference to a preloaded one since all my map segments use the same sprite sheet.

Comment: The speedup wasn't noteworthy since the initialisation of multiple CCTextureAtlases take something about half a second (short but ugly app freezes) plus they take a lot of RAM.